# Why print button always showing when cursor on an image tag in my web page

Tags: asp.net, html, image

I'm have an .aspx page done with Vb.net and the buttons "Save Image" "print image" "Send image" is showing when I put the cursor on one of the images tag. I say one image because it doesn't appear on the other images tags. I don't want these buttons!

Comment: please phrase your question with clear description so that we can understand your need

Answer (score 1):

Are these the buttons?

[ie6 image hover](http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2001/08/03/operating_system/ie6-image-toolbar.jpg)

(I don't know when they appear and when not - check your browser documentation or ask the browser vendor.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the galleryimg tag set on the other images?

```
<img src="proprietary.gif" galleryimg="no" />
```

The 'no' setting will not show the toolbar, while if it is set to 'yes' the toolbar will be visible.

You can also disable this *feature* for the entire page by using the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
```